# How to have StreamReader read 0xDF as an "es zet"?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ms-office

How to have StreamReader read 0xDF as an "es zet"? --- or have MS Word save "es zet" as 0xC3 0x178?

When the German letter "es zet" is copied from MS Access and pasted into Notepad, the "es zet" is saved as a 0xC3 0x178.

When the German letter "es zet" is copied from MS Word and pasted into Notepad, the "es zet" is also saved as a 0xC3 0x178.

When MS Word is saved as a txt, the "es zet" is changed to a 0xDF.

Notepad interprets the 0xC3 0x178 as an "es zet". Notepad also interprets the 0xDF as an "es zet".

StreamReader(stFileName)  reads a 0xC3 0x178 as an "es zet" --- it reads the 0xDF as unknown.

(C#, WPF, Visual Studio 2019, MS Office 2019)

Comment: What do you mean by 0x178? Because hex is usually just 2 digits, this seems to be 178 decimal, not hex.  Anyway, you have to find out the rigth encoding and pass it to [StreamReader(string,encoding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) overload. `0XDF` could be `Windows-1252` or `ISO 8859-1`

Comment: `0xDF` is Windows-1250 code page "ß" while `0xC3` is Utf. You need to use the proper encoding: `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(12050), true);`

Comment: `0xDF` is Windows-1250 (and Windows1252) code page "ß" while `0xC3` is Utf. You need to use the proper encoding: `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save a document as a txt file using MS Word, you get this dialog:

[image: MS Word File Conversion Dialog]

You can see that it's chosen the "Windows (Default)" encoding. This will change based on your computer, but for me (in Western Europe), that's [Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). Looking at it, you can see that ß has the value 0xDF.

On .NET Framework (not .NET Core), the system code page for the current machine is accessible through `Encoding.Default`. So you can use `new StreamReader(stFileName, Encoding.Default)`.

**However**, different machines will use different code pages, which can mess things up. I strongly recommend telling MS Word to save the file as "Unicode (UTF-8)":

[image: MS Word File Conversion Dialog with UTF-8 selected]

You will then be able to read this text file with `new StreamReader(stFileName)`, as `StreamReader` defaults to UTF-8 encoding.